# Install and import Caffe with Anaconda (on Windows 10)

Tags: python, deep-learning, anaconda, conda, caffe

I'm struggling to just install and import `caffe` on my windows 10's Anaconda (`conda 4.7.11`). I really don't know why such a well-known deep-learning package is that hard to just install!

First, I tried to install it. With huge difficulties, I did the following and at last, apparently installation was successful:

```
conda create -n caffe python=3.7
// activate the environment REM Depending on your conda version you may have to use activate caffe

conda activate caffe
// add the anaconda channel to resolve all dependencies

conda config --add channels anaconda
// Install caffe with cuda support or install caffe-cpu if you do not want CUDA support

conda install caffe-cpu -c willyd
```

And now, just trying to `import caffe`, I get this error:

```
>>> import caffe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\caffe\lib\site-packages\caffe\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\caffe\lib\site-packages\caffe\pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What should I do? How to fix it?

BTW, is `Caffe2` different from `Caffe`?

Answer (score 0):

Caffe2 is built on caffe but yes it is different. This link : http://gianni.rosagallina.com/en/posts/2018/10/04/caffe2-gpu-windows-1.html#step-4-build provides a good overview of what steps need to be taken to install caffe2. Incase you hit and error you cannot resolve, you can report the problems on the pytorch git and the team will help you out.